# Некоторые вопросы по ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, .net, веб-программирование, asp.net-mvc

Начал изучать ASP.NET MVC и возникли некоторые вопросы:

1)Чем отличается html тэг помеченные, как asp, от обычного?

Например, `<asp:Label></asp:Label>`

2)В Html редакторе, можно вызывать `@Html.` , которая дает доступ к тэгам в объектной манере.

Я правильно понимаю, что это лишь синтаксический сахар и все это же можно сделать используя обычные Html тэги? Какую нотацию обычно используют объектную или Html или их смешивают?

3)Нет ли помимо Html визуального редактора, который позволит увидеть, как будет выглядеть страница без компиляции?

4)Есть ли в ASP.NET MVC какие-то стандартные контролы помимо Html атрибутов или это доступно только в Web Forms?

Answer (score 2):

1) `asp`-теги это специальные теги обрабатываемые на сервере, они превращаются в обычные HTML-теги, а затем страница отдаётся клиенту.

2) Да, это лишь синтаксический сахар. До появления ASP .NET Core использовали объектную, с появлением ASP .NET Core появились HTML подобные теги, которые, скорее всего, будут более популярные. Но опять же, в каждой организации свои причуды и свои манеры, так что стоит знать и то, и другое.

3) Наверное, нет. Но страницы Razor не компилируется (насколько мне известно), их можно просто перезаписать, обновить в браузере страничку и у Вас подхватится новая версия файла.

4) Стандартные контролы в вебе это HTML контролы, других нет, а сам объект `Html` представляет более удобный доступ к тем же контролам, в объектном стиле, для большего удобства.

Также, Вы можете сами создавать свои теги (TagHelpers). Об этом можно почитать [здесь](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/tag-helpers/authoring).